# How to retrieve the values of the table for the max value of two columns in sql

Tags: mysql, hive, query-optimization, hiveql, impala

I am trying to query a table by taking the maximum values from two different date columns, and output's all the records that have maximum of both the dates

The table has 6 columns which include st_id(string)(there are multiple entries of the same id), as_of_dt(int) and ld_dt_ts(timestamp). From this table, I am trying to get the max value of as_of_dt and ld_dt_ts and group by st_id and display all the records.

### This works perfectly, but its not really optimal

```
SELECT A.st_id, A.fl_vw, A.tr_record FROM db.tablename A 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT st_id, max(as_of_dt) AS as_of_dt, max(ld_dt_ts) AS ld_dt_ts 
    From db.tablename 
    group by st_id
) B on A.st_id = B.st_id and A.as_of_dt = B.as_of_dt and A.ld_dt_ts= B.ld_dt_ts
```

--

The expected result should return the st_id that has the maximum of both as_of_dt and ld_dt_ts i.e., which will be the latest record for each st_id.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Additionally, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: This is classic top records finding task, sql provided is using join, which is not so efficient as analytic functions because require two table scans and a join. I do not think the question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use analytic `rank()` function. `rank()` will assign `1` to all records with max date in the `st_id` partition:

```
SELECT s.st_id, s.fl_vw, s.tr_record
from
(
SELECT A.st_id, A.fl_vw, A.tr_record,
       rank() over(partition by st_id order by as_of_dt desc) rnk_as_of_dt,
       rank() over(partition by st_id order by ld_dt_ts desc) rnk_ld_dt_tsrnk
  FROM db.tablename A 
)s 
WHERE rnk_as_of_dt=1 ANDrnk=1 rnk_ld_dt_ts=1 --get records with max dates in both columns
```

Two ranks can be possibly combined like this:

```
SELECT s.st_id, s.fl_vw, s.tr_record
from
(
SELECT A.st_id, A.fl_vw, A.tr_record,
       rank() over(partition by st_id order by as_of_dt desc, ld_dt_ts desc) rnk
  FROM db.tablename A 
)s 
WHERE rnk=1  --get records with max dates combination
```

but this is not exactly the same as your original query. 
For example if you have this dataset:

```
st_id, as_of_dt, ld_dt_ts 
1       1         2
1       2         1
```

Then this query

```
SELECT st_id, max(as_of_dt) AS as_of_dt, max(ld_dt_ts) AS ld_dt_ts 
    From db.tablename 
    group by st_id
```

will return:

```
st_id, as_of_dt, ld_dt_ts 
1       2         2
```

And final join will not return any rows, because no any row with such combination exist,  while query with two ranks combined will return:

```
st_id, as_of_dt, ld_dt_ts 
1       2         1
```

If such dataset can not exist in your data (say, ld_dt_ts is always>=as_of_dt), then you possibly can combine ranks into single one or even use only one date in the order by.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works really well, good optimization, I was trying a similar approach. Will post it in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

--I am using row_number() function,--

row_number() over(PARTITION BY st_id ORDER BY as_of_dt DESC, ld_dt_ts DESC) RN
from db.tablename s)tmp where RN=1

Comment: This works not exactly the same as your original query in the question. And you said that query in the question works perfectly. Look: Only one row will be marked RN=1, and if you have more than 1 row with max dates, they will not be returned.

Comment: You need rank if you want exactly the same behavior as your initial query with join. And yes, ranks can be combined in to single rank, I edited the answer. But it again depends on the data. If you have st_id=1, dt1=1, dt2=2 and st_id=1, dt1=2, dt2=1 then your max subquery(in the question) will return:  st_id=1, dt1=2, dt2=2  and final join will return no any rows. rank combined query will return 1 row with st_id=1, dt1=2, dt2=1. So, combining two ranks may work not the same

Comment: If we apply some restrictions on your dataset, say for example only one row with max dates can exist for the same id and maybe one more restriction: ld_dt_ts always>=as_of_dt then your row_number can work exactly the same as initial query. And query with two ranks reproduces your original query behavior without any restrictions on the dataset